# retrieving images from a pygame interface

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am building a screen using pygame to create a grid interface (3*3) like so :

```
screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height + 100), 0, 32)
```

After that i am pasting images at each of the 9 available spots of the grid with the coordinates `posy` and `posx` on the grid as parameters like so :

```
screen.blit(img, (posy, posx))
```

Is there a way to retrieve each of the pasted images ? what would be the returning type to further process the image ?

EDIT : you mean something like this to store the state ?

```
class Cell : 
    image = ''
    posX = 0
    posY = 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: What you have done with `Cell` would use class variables as opposed to instance variables (which you create in the __init__() and are prefixed with `self`). You want instances. See my edited answer for how you could declare the `Cell` class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to ask if: after the 9 images have been `blit()`ed to the `screen` can you later somehow ask the `screen` which images were `blit()`ed to each area are, then no. The `screen` is just a bunch of pixels that have been set to certain values by `blit()`s. It has no idea where those values came from.

You have to track that yourself. I would recommend creating a cell object where 9 instances of it make up your grid and would keep the state for each of the 9 areas in the grid including the image for  that area. You might find subclassing `Sprite` to be useful.

Edit:

For example you could do something like this for the `Cell`:

```py
class Cell():
    def __init__(self, pos, image, row, column):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, image.get_size())
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
```

or if you want to do more with it later (which I will not include here), you might want to subclass [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) like this:

```py
class Cell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, image, row, column):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, image.get_size())
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
```

In either case you would likely add more to the class, but in the first example even this limited way allows you to keep all the state information together for each instance. Using a Class with just the `__init__()` and no other methods is a bit like a struct in C, it allows you to organize and structure your data.

Comment: You totally get i mean but can you further explain how i can track this myself ?

Comment: As I said, define a `Cell` class that keeps track of all the state information for that cell/area. When you divide you grid into 9 areas allocate an instance of `Cell` to each area and have it save the state information for that area (like the image, position,  row, column, etc). When you want to redraw it you can use that. Or if you are trying to determine what image is in a certain area you can find the `Cell` that is over that area and look at what image the `Cell` is using.

Comment: pls see EDIT above

Comment: Alright for your EDIT, but then i would have to use a Class List to store class instances for the states of the 9 spots ?

Comment: Yes, The instances would have to be saved in a list

Comment: If you did them as a subclass of Sprite then you would use pygames Sprite Groups as the collection. If you did that you would call the Groups `draw()` method to draw/redraw them all.